# Pytest.paramterize Needs to run on a list which is generated by another pytest test

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, pytest

I'm trying to use the pytest.parametrize to use a param (list) in a test method. The tricky bit is that the  list is being generated by another test method :

```
list_testing = []


class TestScratch(object):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        pass


    # @classmethod
    # def setup_method(cls):
    #     pass


    def test_populate_list(self):
        # will read content of list from file as part of the test
        for i in range(100):
            list_testing.append(i)
        assert len(list_testing)>50

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("number", list_testing)
    def test_pytest_param(self, number):
        assert type(number) == int
```

If i place the list population outside of the class it works fine but when i try to ecute in the above shown way i get the following results:

```
scratch.py::TestScratch::test_populate_list PASSED                                                                                                                
scratch.py::TestScratch::test_pytest_param[number0] SKIPPED
```

Comment: So again - this code doesn't show that, but you are saying that your test data depends on the test itself? Can you elaborate a bit why this is so? Just loading and parsing a file would not be dependent on the test.

Comment: True , but if i'm not able to parse the file (to different parameters ) then there will be no point in running the tests

Comment: Well, if you don't get parameters out of the file, you will return an empty list, and the real test will just be skipped as it does now for your example - while the parameter test will fail (I have updated the answer on the first question to include that test)

Comment: Thank you for your help. will have to see what would be the correct way